# Do Lag Seeing and Gauche Suede have eyebrows?

Tags: tegami-bachi

I noticed something very perplexing while watching the *Tegami Bachi* anime: Gauche Suede and Lag Seeing don't appear to have eyebrows. This is a perplexing situation because they both have long hair that could be hiding their eyebrows. To make matters worse, the tops of their eyelids are both prominently drawn, so it's possible that I'm mistaking some of the lines for their eyebrows for their eyelids.

There doesn't seem to be a relationship between this shared feature and that both characters are Albisian, since Sylvette and Doctor Thunderland Jr. both have eyebrows (although notably, according to the [wiki](http://tegamibachi.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Thunderland_Jr.), it isn't confirmed that Doctor Thunderland is an Albisian).

This issue is so distracting that I find myself searching for their eyebrows whenever either one of them appears. Do Lag and Gauche have eyebrows? Is there any point in the anime or manga that clearly shows their eyebrows (or lack of eyebrows) or does a character ever acknowledge they don't have eyebrows?

Comment: Seems some viewers/readers also have the same opinion with you. Even the eyebrows are not drawn (or, hidden) in the manga too. One also had the same guess about Albisian's characteristic, but then refuted themself because of other Albisian character having eyebrows.

Comment: @AkiTanaka That's reassuring to hear. I was a tad worried it was just a misunderstanding on my part.